# Android Service Does Not Start No Matter What Method Is Used

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, alarm

I have a service I'm attempting to start but nothing within the service seems to be executing. I've added toasts for testing purposes but nothing seems to be happening. (I believe the problem lies within the service starter section of my code.)

Any suggestions?

- Amani Swann

SERVICE STARTER SOURCE:

```
public class ServiceStarter extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startService(new Intent(this, DataCountService.class));

    }
}
```

SERVICE SOURCE CODE:

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USI;0; 0375515651;21/45/37/01/07/14;CN100.757,WN300.545;CO100.554,WO20.747";
    String ERROR = "DataCountService";
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final long PERIOD = 1000 * 15; // x min
    private final long DELAY_INTERVAL = 0; // x Seconds

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId) {

        // display test toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing 4,5,6 - GO! GO! GO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
        if (text.contains("USI;1;")) {


            // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
            double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
            double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                    + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
            totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
            totalBytes /= 1000000;
            mobileBytes /= 1000000;
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
            String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
            String info = String.format("WN%s,CN%s", totalStr, mobileStr);


            // send traffic info via sms
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("7862611848", null, info, null, null);
            String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
        } else if

        (text.contains("USI;1;")) {
            stopSelf();


            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other character
        } else {

            Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();


                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (text.contains("USI;1;")) {


                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String info = String.format("WN%s,CN%s", totalStr,
                            mobileStr);

                    // save data in sharedPreferences

                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences("WifiData", 0);
                    Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    // send SMS (including current Wifi usage and last month's
                    // data
                    // as well)
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("WN" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("DN" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage("7862611848", null,
                            sms + pref.getString("last_month", ""), null, null);

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
                } else if

                (text.contains("USI;1;")) {
                    stopSelf();


                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other character
                } else {

                    Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

                }

            }
        }, DELAY_INTERVAL, PERIOD);
    }



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

UPDATED SOURCE (BASED ON COMMENTS BELOW - AS OF 12:00pm EST)

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USI;0; 0375515651;21/45/37/01/07/14;CN100.757,WN300.545;CO100.554,WO20.747";
    String ERROR = "DataCountService";
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private final long PERIOD = 1000 * 15; // x min
    private final long DELAY_INTERVAL = 0; // x Seconds

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int  onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        // display test toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Testing 1,2,3 - GO! GO! GO!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
        if (text.contains("USI;1;")) {

            // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
            double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                    + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
            double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                    + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
            totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
            totalBytes /= 1000000;
            mobileBytes /= 1000000;
            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
            String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
            String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
            String info = String.format("WN%s,CN%s", totalStr, mobileStr);

            // send traffic info via sms
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage("7865555555", null, info, null, null);
            String alarm = Context.ALARM_SERVICE;

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
        } else if

        (text.contains("USI;1;")) {
            stopSelf();

            // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other character
        } else {

            Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    private void startServiceTimer() {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

                // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to enable
                if (text.contains("USI;1;")) {

                    // get Wifi and Mobile traffic info
                    double totalBytes = (double) TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
                    double mobileBytes = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();
                    totalBytes -= mobileBytes;
                    totalBytes /= 1000000;
                    mobileBytes /= 1000000;
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
                    String totalStr = nf.format(totalBytes);
                    String mobileStr = nf.format(mobileBytes);
                    String info = String.format("WN%s,CN%s", totalStr,
                            mobileStr);

                    // save data in sharedPreferences

                    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                            .getSharedPreferences("WifiData", 0);
                    Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString("last_month", info);
                    editor.commit();

                    // send SMS (with Wifi usage and last month's Data usage) 
                    String sms = "";
                    sms += ("WN" + (TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()
                            + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - (TrafficStats
                            .getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes())) / 1000000);
                    sms += ("DN" + (TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + TrafficStats
                            .getMobileTxBytes()) / 1000000);

                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage("7865555555", null,
                            sms + pref.getString("last_month", ""), null, null);

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to disable
                } else if

                (text.contains("USI;1;")) {
                    stopSelf();

                    // check for Enable or Disable Value - if set to any other
                    // character
                } else {

                    Log.e(ERROR, "Invalid Enable/Disable Value");

                }

            }
        }, DELAY_INTERVAL, PERIOD);


    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }

}
```

Comment: you are missing the @Override above the onStartCommand?

Comment: adding one results in the error - The method onStartCommand(Intent, int) of type DataCountService must override or implement a supertype method

Comment: You are missing one last parameter which is int startId. change your onStartCommand declaration in onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)

Comment: @user2497481 This means you are not overriding the method you should because of wrong parameter types or count

Comment: Have you made entry to AndroidManifest.xml ??

Comment: @Override
 public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)  {

Results in "The return type is incompatible with Service.onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)"

Comment: Yes I have made the entry in the manifest

Comment: onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) returns an `int`. Return one of the values defined in the `Service` class, like `START_NOT_STICKY`

Comment: I changed it to public int  onStartCommand and used return START_NOT_STICKY; but now all of a sudden it's force closing with a java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service - NullPointerException error

Comment: Any suggestions? [I added updated source above]

Comment: I recommend adding some breakpoints and debugging the service to find the source of the NPE